# Which component does the Linux bug "reboot instead of shutdown" have?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bugs

I'm trying to get a [reboot instead of shutdown bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197871) and would like to attract more attention to it by changing the product and component. Which one is better than "Other"? I checked all of them and none seems matching well, but I'm sure, I'm missing something.

I assumed that the issues are reviewed and the product and category eventually adjusted by users with necessary permissions.

Comment: Is this a question about the Linux kernel bugzilla interface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about picking a field for a bugzilla web page.

Answer (score 2):

I would set the product to "Platform Specific/Hardware" because that's what it seems to be. The `reboot` behavior you are describing in the launchpad report seems to be closely tied to your laptop's mainboard. Possibly this could also go under "ACPI", but I think that would require further analysis from someone more knowledgeable with how shutdown/reboot works on different platforms.